# Import Excel files with different Date types

Tags: r, date

Got a lot of Excel files, all containing the same columns. One of the columns is called "DateTime". The problem is, that this column contain different formats, e.g:

```
2/12/2013  11:59:45 PM
20/2/2013 14:36:58
```

As you can see, the first example contains a PM at the end. Here is my problem:

My code to import all the Excel files in the specific folder:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
df <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "id")
```

But, after I run the second line (`df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)`) I got a warnings like (Expecting numeric, got a date).

I tried different things, such as assigning `col_types = "text"` (I hoped that I could import all the data as character, and afterwards change remove the PM at the end and change the characters back to `as.Date` again). But unfortunately the results was a lot of `NA`'s.

Another thing that I tried was to import the the file as numeric (but again, received the same message "Expecting numeric, got a date).

So how can I tackle this problem? I can do it by changing the columns type in Excel, but that is not what I want to do (I prefer to do everything in R).

**Edit**

Some data as requested (after I imported the data into R with as "character" with the lubridate as_date function, as suggested).

```
Num Date
1  41277.000601851854
2  41277.004710648151
3  41277.004826388889
4  41277.007372685184
5  41277.007789351854
6  41277.007870370369
7  41277.010335648149
8  41277.010868055557
9  41277.013842592591
10 41277.014548611114
```

Answer (score 2):

`lubridate` has the excellent `parse_date_time` function, you can specify the orders of day/month/year and also 'truncate', e.g. allow for some formats to have missing numbers.

```
library(lubridate)

time <- c("2/12/2013 11:59:45 PM", "20/2/2013 14:36:58")
parse_date_time(time, orders = c('dmyHMS') )

[1] "2013-12-02 11:59:45 UTC" "2013-02-20 14:36:58 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks, works for one part (dealing with the different types of dates). But then I still got the trouble to import the data in R. Do you have any idea how that could be solved?

Comment: I tend to try and avoid Excel files, can you open it and save as a .csv file - if impossible, have a look at the `readxl` package and `read.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package, I've used both in the past - but tend to stick with `readxl`

Answer (score 1):

First read in all data as char strings, it will be easy to clean afterwards.

Then I think the `lubridate` package could help you here. I don't know how many files/formats you have but the example given can be read by the same `lubridate::dmy_hms()` function:

```
# >datim <- c("20/2/2013 14:36:58", "2/12/2013  11:59:45 PM")
# >dmy_hms(datim)
# [1] "2013-02-20 14:36:58 UTC" "2013-12-02 23:59:45 UTC"
```

There is a function for each ordering of time units. `mdy_hm()` for example. If you have more variation in your time formats you would use `stringr::str_detect(your_date_variable, "date_format_regex")` to identify lines with each type of format before applying the appropriate dmy_hm() function.

Comment: I tried to read in the data as char strings, but the only options for "col_type" are: "skip", "guess", "logical", "numeric", "date", "text" or "list". 

I guess I'm wrong, but I thought that character == text. But the values are changing, so the result is: 

    DateTime
    41277.000601851854   and   
    41277.004710648151

And if I convert this back with the function as.Date(DateTime), I got not the years that I have, see: "2083-01-05"

Comment: Sorry yes "text" is for charachter strings. The numbers 41277.000/... represent days since  1/1/1901. You can extract the date using lubridate `as_date("1900-01-01") + seconds(41277.000601851854 * 24 * 60 * 60)` gives `#[1] "2013-01-05 00:00:52 UTC"`

Comment: Great! Make sense, but when I run your code:  as_date("1900-01-01") + seconds(41277.000601851854 * 24 * 60 * 60) I got the results: [1] "1831-12-13 20:45:52 UTC"

Comment: Can you post up a short extract of your data? Might have time to have a play with it over the weekend ...

Comment: Sure, but it is not really interesting I guess. I posted the data after I imported the data in R (with the lubridate as_date function).